# Will adding earthworms to my lawn enrich the soil?

Tags: lawn, earthworms

I want to put some earthworms in my lawn to enrich the soil.  Will it work?

Comment: Questions of where to buy things are off-topic here because the site has a worldwide audience and knowing the names of sellers that are near isn't going to help the vast majority of people. Please see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/teaching-a-man-to-fish-garden-and-shop for more information about this policy. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: This question is not a shopping question. On-topic.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. If there are no earthworms present, it's because the area is inhospitable to them, so any you try to add will just disappear. Usually, people don't want too much earthworm activity in a lawn because of the little piles they leave on the top of the lawn during damp periods in spring and autumn, but if you live somewhere hot and dry, you may never see those anyway.

You don't say where you are, or what type of grass  your lawn is comprised of, but in the UK, lawn maintenance such as scarifying, aerating and top dressing will improve the fertility of  the soil and health of the lawn, making earthworm activity more likely. Information on top dressing here https://www.lovethegarden.com/uk-en/article/top-dressing-lawn-how-and-why